# SpringCloud's /refresh not effective on properties used in camel routes

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

**Camel version** : *2.22.0*

**SpringBoot Version** : *2.0.2.RELEASE*

**Observation**: the config properties, which ideally have to be updated as they are changed in the configuration service and when a refresh is done at the Client service, does not take effect in case of properties that are used inside a Camel Route.
**Note: there is a ticket in Jira whihc says fixed. but which release has this? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-8482**

Adding the code segment:
The class which contains below code segment is annotated with `@Component` and `@RefreshScope`

```
@Value("${prop}")
String prop;
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {



from("direct:route1").routeId("Child-1")
    .setHeader( Exchange.CONTENT_ENCODING, simple("gzip"))
    .setBody(simple("RESPONSE - [ {  \"id\" : \"bf383eotal length is 16250]]"))
    .log(prop + "${body}")
    ;
```

Comment: refreshing will only work for `@RefreshScope` scoped beans. I doubt those camel routes are scoped like that.

Comment: @yuriv Tsarkov the Component annotated class which contains the camel routes is annotated with RefreshScope.

Comment: Show the configuration. If it is the component using the route it doesn't change a thing.

Comment: @Value("${prop}")
 String prop;
-----------------------------------
from("direct:route1").routeId("Child-1")
 .setHeader( Exchange.CONTENT_ENCODING, simple("gzip"))
 .setBody(simple("RESPONSE - [ {  \"id\" : \"bf383eotal length is 16250]]"))
 .log(prop + "${body}")
 ;

Comment: Don't add additional configuration as comments those are unreadable... Edit your question.

Comment: sorry, I could not get that. @M.Deinum. I just updated my previous edit.

Comment: I have no clue on what your comments should add. The code is unreadable, your explanation doesn't add anything. As stated edit your question instead o adding code as comments (click the edit link and update the question).

Comment: the question is updated.

Comment: As it is a camel route, I doubt the refreshed bean (if it gets refreshed) will be called again by Camel to reconfigure the route. I doubt that Camel detects that and acts upon it.

Comment: @M.Deinum Actually, it does not work even if you refresh any Spring Bean, from which Camel consumes. Seems like Camel is caching internally.